# Geometrical generalization of Pythagorean Theorem.

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

In the below article at maa [site](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834204333.di020735.02p0046r.pdf), there is geometrical proof for a generalization of the Pythagorean Theorem. 
The problem given is :- Given two right triangles show that cc' = aa' + bb'. 
 I request the reason for the equality of the fractions $\frac{x}{b} = \frac{b'}{a}$ chosen as following some law of congruency, which is not given.
 [image]

---

*Edit* As an additional request, if possible please help me identify what type of journal, is this page part of.

Comment: Assuming that $a$ is the hypotenuse of the big triangle (and not just the hypotenuse $-a'$), this is clearer if you write it as $\frac x{b'}=\frac ba$.

Comment: The College Mathematics Journal, 20(1), p. 58 --- It's from Jan, 1989.

Comment: @user537566 Thanks a lot. I hope by experience you would have found that out.

Comment: More generally, given similar triangles with sides $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$ and $a_2$, $b_2$, $c_2$, we have $$c_1 c_2 = a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2 - 2 \sqrt{a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2}\,\cos C$$

Comment: @Blue Please elaborate your statement. I need more detail to understand without any confusion. I also admire the detail given, but it is better if some more elaboration is done.

Comment: @jiten: In the same way that the result you mention generalizes the Pythagorean Theorem, the result I mention generalizes the Law of Cosines: $$c^2=a^2+b^2−2ab \cos C$$
The proof is a simple application of the Law of Sines: If the triangles have circumdiameters $d_1$ and $d_2$, then the Law of Sines allows us to write
$$a_i=d_i \sin A\qquad b_i = d_i \sin B \qquad c_i=d_i \sin C$$
Substituting these into the formula I gave, we can divide-through by $d_1d_2$ to get
$$\sin^2 C = \sin^2 A + \sin^2 B−2\sin A \sin B \cos C$$
which holds for $A+B+C=180^\circ$.